# Is it possible to enumerate network root using Qt classes?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, filesystems, qtsystems

Qt file API classes handle network folder paths correctly on Windows. But I can’t find a way to enumerate network root (list of network drives and computers available). Is there any way to do that without using WinAPI but only Qt classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid, the best you can get is [QStorageInfo](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/5.0-snapshot/qstorageinfo/#alllogicaldrives-prop) from QtSystems.

> [allLogicalDrives : const QStringList](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/5.0-snapshot/qstorageinfo/#alllogicaldrives-prop)
>
> This property holds the list of all drives.
>
> Returns a list of all logical drives or volumes, or an empty list if no drives are found or on error.

Then, you have methods to query the uri, filter based on "remote" type, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this library, certainly will come in handy.